# Изменить цвета меток на готовой яндекс карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Требуется встроить себе на сайт карту https://yandex.ru/maps/covid19

Через API Яндекс.Карт не понял как использовать готовую карту + нужно изменить цвета меток. Заранее благодарен тому, кто подскажет в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Яндекс отдельно данные карты коронавируса через API не дает, только карту целиком.

Они довольно давно добавили возможность подключить карту распространения коронавируса на сайт через iframe. Инструкции есть на GitHub: https://github.com/ymaps/covid19-map-embed/

Кроме того добавив /isolation в URL кода можно получить карту самоизоляции (ныне активности), а не распространения. Но данные по городам России Яндекс уже убрал, отались одни столицы.

А добавив координаты центра с зумом можно получить подобие виджета с этим индексом для конкретного региона. Ранее это были города, сейчас информация доступна только по областям.
Пример кода для Владимирской области:

```
<iframe src="https://yandex.ru/maps/covid19?embed=covid-map&ll=40.886372%2C56.096090&z=9
" width="400px" height="350px"></iframe>
```

Координаты и масштаб можно скопировать из адресной строки на Яндекс.Картах - это параметры ll= и z= соответственно.

При этом задать зум более 7 возможно, но при сдвиге карты масштаб сбросится на 7-ку.

Метки сейчас вроде задаются классом .covid-placemark.ru для России и .covid-placemark для остального мира. Если поменяете их background-color, изменится и цвет.

Но всё это временные действия. Документации подробной Яндекс не даёт, значит поменять всё могут в любой момент.